# Use INSERT information from trigger in another insert

Tags: sql, sql-server, triggers, sql-insert

I am writing a trigger `after insert` that inserts data in another table using the inserted data. *This part, I figured out*
But then, I want to use that freshly inserted data, to insert in **another** table.

```
CREATE TRIGGER [dbo].[tr_Subsite_Insert]
   ON  [dbo].[Subsite]
   AFTER INSERT
AS 
BEGIN


    INSERT INTO TranslationKey
        SELECT 'base.' + inserted.[name] + '.' + sst.name FROM SubsiteText sst
            CROSS JOIN inserted

    --Use the result of the above INSERT to insert in another table.
    --Example code below:
    INSERT INTO Translation
       SELECT lng.id, inserted2.id, '' FROM Languages lng
       CROSS JOIN inserted2
    --Obviously, "inserted2" doesn't exist.

END
GO
```

How can I get the values from the first insert, to use them in the 2nd insert?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have 2 options here:

1. Create another trigger on `TranslationKey` table (this is straightforward)
2. Use `OUTPUT` keyword(I will elaborate on this)

Declare a table variable and use `OUTPUT` keyword to grab newly inserted `ID`s. Then use that temp table in the `CROSS JOIN`. Here is an example:

```
/*here you should change UNIQUEIDENTIFIER to 
  actual type of ID column in TranslationKey table*/
DECLARE @t TABLE ( ID UNIQUEIDENTIFIER )

INSERT  INTO TranslationKey
OUTPUT  INSERTED.ID
        INTO @t
        SELECT  'base.' + inserted.[name] + '.' + sst.name
        FROM    SubsiteText sst
                CROSS JOIN inserted

INSERT  INTO Translation
        SELECT  lng.id ,
                t.ID ,
                ''
        FROM    Languages lng
                CROSS JOIN @t t
```

Comment: Thank you, I'll go check the 2nd option in a second. About the 1st option: yea, that's straightforward, but the problem is that I use the other table for other situations, independent of this one, as well. :)

Comment: I have an error: (in French sadly): `Msg 206, Level 16, State 2, Procedure tr_SubSite_Insert, Line 18
Conflit de types d'opérandes : int est incompatible avec uniqueidentifier` which means: "Operand type conflict: int is incompatible with uniqueidentifier". Any idea where this comes from?

Comment: @Jordumus, I don't know the type of `ID` column in `TranslationKey` table, so instead of `DECLARE @t TABLE ( ID UNIQUEIDENTIFIER )` replace with appropriate type `DECLARE @t TABLE ( ID appropriateType of ID column )`

Comment: Yeah, sorry, figured that one out myself after hitting my head 3 times against the wall. I really should think twice before just braindeath-asking questions. :)